# How are inner observables disposed in RxJava 2?

Tags: java, rx-java

Im sorry if this has been answered previously, but from my searching I cant find it and Im really curious to understand how this works under the hood - if it does...

Say I have one PublishSubject that takes a string like this:

```
PublishSubject<String> trigger = PublishSubject.create();
```

I use this together with another observable:

```
Observable<String> obs1 = trigger.filter(new Predicate<String>(){
    @Override
    public boolean test(String s) throws Exception{
        return s != null;
    }
});

Observable<String> obs2 = Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<String>(){
    @Override
    public void subscribe(final ObservableEmitter<String> e) throws Exception {
        //When/is this ever disposed? 
        obs1.subscribe(new Consumer<String>(){
            @Override
            public void accept(String s){
                //Never called after obs1 is disposed.
                e.onNext(s);
            }
        }        
    }
});

//A
Disposable disposable = obs2.subscribe(new Consumer<String>(){
    public void accept(String s){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
});


trigger.onNext("Holahoop"); //Above "A" is called.

disposable.dispose();

trigger.onNext("Hakuna Matata"); //Nothing happens.
```

### Expectation:

The obs1 subscription is called, e.onNext is called but since its been disposed - the call trace ends there.

### Reality

Obs 1 subscription is not called at all. Even though I havent explicitly unsubscribed from it.

### My question

Why is that? Is it automatically unsubscribed/disposed under the hood? Is it GCd when the outer observable is disposed? Please enlighten me!

*Note 1: This is using RxJava 2.0.0-RC3.*

*Note 2: Pseudo code, so sorry for slight errors (if any).*

Answer (score 0):

Works as expected. If you'd put a `System.out.println(s)` into `obs2` you'd see that it receives the "Hakuna Matata" but won't relay it further since you disposed its consumer. If you keep references to any of the local variables they won't be garbage collected.